# Google Apps Script: Add event to shared Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

first time asking something here! :)

So I wrote/copied a short script to add an event to my Google Calendar:

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('FooBar');
 
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process - 2 exempts my header row
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
 
  var complete = "Done";
 
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    Logger.log(row[0]);
    var name = row[0]; //Item Name
    var notes = row[3];  //Notes
    var startDate = new Date(row[1]);  //renewal date
    var endDate = new Date(row[2]); //remind date
    var eventID = row[6]; //event marked Done
   
    if (eventID != complete) {
      var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
      calendar.createEvent(name, startDate, endDate, {
        description: notes
      });
    
      currentCell.setValue(complete);
    }
  }
}
```

This works great, but isn't really the solution to my problem.
So straight to my question:
Is it posible to add events to someone elses calendar (maybe with ICAL?)

Also my Sheet looks like that:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT7Mn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have edit rights on the imported calendar then you can add a event to it. Just change the id (`FooBar`) to the right one. With this little script you output the calanders with some info to the console.

```
function readCalanders () {
  CalendarApp.getAllCalendars().forEach(cal => {
    console.log({
      name: cal.getName(), 
      id: cal.getId(),
      primary: cal.isMyPrimaryCalendar(),
      owendByMe: cal.isOwnedByMe()
      })
  })
}
```